# Launch Silverlight Out of Browser App Programmatically

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to use SLLAUNCHER.EXE to launch an SL Out-of-Browser App that is installed. The MyApp startup icon on the desktop just disappears after I run the below. If I try it without the overwrite switch nothing happens.

I am using this article as a guide:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sllauncherPath = string.Format("{0}\\Microsoft Silverlight\\sllauncher.exe",
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles));

        string originUri = @"http://localhost:52878/ClientBin/MyApp.xap";
        string xap = "MyApp.xap";
        string arg = string.Format(@"/emulate:""{0}"" /origin:""{1}""  /overwrite", xap, originUri);

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            FileName = sllauncherPath,
            Arguments = arg
        };

       var process = Process.Start(startInfo))

    }
```

Comment: does it work or is there a question?

Comment: I'm trying to get the same thing to work.  It appears there may be a bug in Silverlight 4, causing sllauncher.exe to fail silently.  In any case, I'll continue to look into it.  Perhaps there's a workaround.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/575052/sllauncher-exe-fails-silently-and-runs-nothing-with-emulate-option

Comment: I attempted the exact same code with my app in the hopes that I could simply use an external application to programmatically launch my OOB silverlight application installed on the same box and got the same results. My desktop shortcut to my OOB app disappeared and a window for the OOB silverlight did display. I pass init params in my hosted version which are causing it not to load OOB so I'm not 100% it loads as expected quite yet, but a window does pop with the expected title in the window title bar.

Answer (score 0):

Are You using 64bit machine?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightcontrols/thread/abedb9dc-d471-4d82-8a20-45f98671cac9

**Could allso help:**
This is how I do restart from within my SL OOB apps after I detect update has completed:

```
''put this in your App.xaml.vb[.cs] and call DoRestart
Public Shared Sub DoRestart()
    StartAgain()
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()
End Sub
Public Shared Sub StartAgain()
    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(GetSLLauncherCommand) Then
        Using shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            shell.Run(GetSLLauncherCommand)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
Public Shared Function GetSLLauncherCommand() As String
    Dim desktopPath As String
    Dim SLLauncherCommand As String = ""
    Using wShell As Object = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        desktopPath = wShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    End Using
    Using shell As Object = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Dim DesktopFolder As Object = shell.[NameSpace](desktopPath)
        Dim DesktopItems As Object = DesktopFolder.Items()
        For Each item In DesktopItems
            If item.IsLink Then 'this is a shurtcut
                Dim fileName As String = item.Name.ToLower()

                If fileName.Contains("!!!<PART OF YOUR SL APPS SHORCUT NAME>!!!!") Then
                    Dim link = item.GetLink()
                    SLLauncherCommand = """" & Convert.ToString(link.Path) & """ " & Convert.ToString(link.Arguments)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Using
    Return SLLauncherCommand
End Function
```

You could try adapt the code for Your non-SL app!

THT